# About validates inclusion

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have:

```
AMOUNT = { '$ 0.50' => 0.5, '$ 1' => 1, '$ 2' => 2, '$ 5' => 5, '$ 10' => 10 }
```

Isn't:

```
validates :amount, :inclusion => { :in => %w(0.5 1 2 5 10), :message => '%{value} is not a valid amount' }
```

the same thing as:

```
validates :amount, :inclusion => { :in => AMOUNT.values, :message => '%{value} is not a valid amount' }
```

With the former, everything works. With the latter, every time I submit, I get the validation message...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first one:

```
:in => %w(0.5 1 2 5 10)
```

your `:in` is an array of Strings. In your second one:

```
:in => AMOUNT.values
```

your `:in` is an array of Floats and Fixnums. Apparently your `amount` is a String during validation and `10 != '10'` is true.

Try changing the values in your `AMOUNT` to Strings or do the conversion when you build `:in`:

```
:in => AMOUNT.values.map(&:to_s)
```